# This is continually showing in the syslog. I know it's mail generated but what?

Tags: macos

Oddly recurring message in syslog.
Note that the warning message in Syslog, isn't proceeded by any SASL warnings. Unless "Mail[378]" is exactly that.

```
Mail[378]: No worthy mechs found
```

I can't find any solution to this, and basically have no idea what it's referring to? So if anyone knows, I'd love to hear about it. postfi-3.1+dovecot+sasl+tls+mysql on OSX 10.10.3

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from a pam configuration that seems to be generated by Mail.app looking to login when it can't. It is a TLS/SASL problem, that I still haven't got to the bottom of. However - the message has gone away.